# Concatenate multiple data sets with same HEADER format

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have following file Hello.txt with below data

```
HEAD 0010 YYYY
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0010 04
HEAD 0001 YYYY
A
B
C
TAIL 0001 03
HEAD 0002 YYYY
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0002 04
HEAD 0001 YYYY
A
B
C
D
E
TAIL 0001 05
HEAD 0003 YYYY
A
B
TAIL 0003 02
```

**Here I want to extract certain rows matching a format , (HEAD + 0001 and TAIL + 0001) , merge body records together eliminating identical HEAD and TAIL records and updating the TAIL record with Body record count (08).
**

Expected output format below #

```
HEAD 0010 YYYY
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0010 04
HEAD 0002 YYYY
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0002 04
HEAD 0003 YYYY
A
B
TAIL 0003 02
HEAD 0001 YYYY
A
B
C
A
B
C
D
E
TAIL 0001 08
```

Comment: You mentioned you need values  of `HEAD + 0001 to TAIL + 0001` but I could see values of HEAD 200 too along with TAIL 200, could you please clarify more on same?

Comment: TAIL 0001 08 is in the expected output but not in the input.

Comment: hey Raman, yes the objective is to combine data sets for 0001 block and just have one header and trailer and updating the trailer with the combined body record count for 0001 datasets.

Here first 0001 data set has 3 records and second 0001 data set has 5 records. Updating the trailer with combined  body record count = 5 + 3 = 8

Comment: Is there any particular order for the output sections?

Comment: A video with some thougts for inspiration:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd8ulMb6_ls

Comment: @VPfB I **really** liked the question about `ansible` ;D

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags that you apply. Hint: At least one of them is wrong!

Comment: The linked video is about writing Python scripts. I'd like to note that this question had a `[Python]` tag in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python implementation using a regex:

```
import re 

pat=r'^HEAD[ \t]+(\d+)([\s\S]+?)^TAIL[ \t]+(\1)'

with open(ur_file) as f:
    data=f.read()
    blocks={}
    for block in re.finditer(pat, data, flags=re.M):
        blocks.setdefault(block.group(1), 
               []).extend([r for r in block.group(2).split('\n') if r])
        
for k,v in blocks.items():
    cnt=len(v)
    data='\n'.join(v)
    print(f'HEAD {k}\n{data}\nTAIL {k} {cnt}')
```

Prints:

```
HEAD 0010
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0010 4
HEAD 0001
A
B
C
A
B
C
D
E
TAIL 0001 8
HEAD 0002
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0002 4
HEAD 0003
A
B
TAIL 0003 2
```

The regex `r'^HEAD[ \t]+(\d+)([\s\S]+?)^TAIL[ \t]+(\1)'` matches blocks of records as can be seen in this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnctLm/1).

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6+ for the f strings?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: OP has modified the desired output to include a requirement for fixed width output on the `HEAD/TAIL` records; should be doable by modifying the `printf` formats; OP can tweak as needed ... use negative format numbers to left-justify, positive numbers to right-justify, then adjust the numbers for the desired width ...

---

Assumptions based on sample data:

- OP wants to consolidate the rows for a specific pattern (eg, `0001`)
- the consolidated rows are to be moved to the end of the output
- there is no need to (re)sort the overall dataset based on pattern ordering (ie, no need to order as `0001`, `0002`, `0003`, `0010`)

One `awk` solution:

```
pattern='0001'

awk -v ptn="${pattern}" '                            # pass pattern in as awk variable "ptn"
$0 ~ "^HEAD "ptn"$" { save=1 ; next }                # start of group => set save flag; skip to next line
$0 ~ "^TAIL "ptn" " { save=0 ; next }                # end of group => clear save flag; skip to next line
save                { ++i ; line[i]=$0 ; next }      # if save=1 then store current line in next position of array line[]; skip to next line
                    { print }                        # otherwise print all other lines to stdout

END { if ( i >= 1 )                                  # if we found any matches ...
         { printf "%-561s%s", "HEAD", ptn            # print the new "HEAD" line
           for ( j=1 ; j<=i ; j++ )                  # then loop through our list of indices ...
               { print line[j] }                     # printing the associated line[] element
           fmt="TAIL %s %02i\n"                      # left pad the count with zero ...
           printf "%-69s%-491s%02i" "TAIL", i, ptn   # print the "TAIL" line
         }
     }
' hello.txt
```

**NOTE**: remove comments to declutter code

The above generates:

```
HEAD 0010
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0010 04
HEAD 0002
A
B
C
D
TAIL 0002 04
HEAD 0003
A
B
TAIL 0003 02
HEAD                                        0001 ('0001' starts in column 562)
A
B
C
A
B
C
D
E
TAIL       08 ('08' starts in column 70)    0001 ('0001' starts in column 562)
```

Comment: You don't need a special `if` for `i>99` -- for larger numbers the leading 0 is not printed: `awk 'BEGIN {printf "%02d\n", 100}'`

Comment: sorry, I'm not following what you're saying re: `position starts at 68`; could you update the question, making sure to note where these `68 spaces` are showing up in the input/output data ... ?

Comment: you now have two sets of expected output; please combine these into one set of expected output so that we have a (more) clear idea of what's required; if the inputs also have the 68/580 spaces, then update the sample input, too; you don't necessarily have to place 68/560 spaces in each HEAD/TAIL line but at least do something like `HEAD<560 spaces>0001` and `TAIL<68 spaces>0001`; regardless, I've updated the answer with some ideas ... you basically just have to use the correct number in the format string

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: when I posted this, the question had a `[Python]` tag. The tag was later removed.**

In simple Python:

```
import collections

# read into memory    
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('datafile') as f:
    section = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('HEAD'):
            section = line.split()[1]
        elif line.startswith('TAIL'):
            # OPTIONAL: check if section id matches
            section = None
        else:
            # OPTIONAL: check if section is not None
            data[section].append(line)

# write to output
for section, lines in data.items():
    print(f"HEAD {section}")
    for line in lines:
        print(line, end='')
    print(f"TAIL {section} {len(lines):02}")
```

Answer (score 0):

this uses GNU awk for the multi-dimensional arrays:

```sh
gawk '
    $1 == "HEAD" {key = $2; next}
    $1 == "TAIL" {next}
    {lines[key][++count[key]] = $0}
    END {
        for (key in count) {
            print "HEAD", key
            for (i=1; i<=count[key]; i++) print lines[key][i]
            printf "TAIL %s %02d\n", key, count[key]
        }
    }
' file
```